# Use JPA to store data in Array-list of coordinates as a polygon in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
    "boundary": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            -73.9493302,
            40.7851967
          ],
          [
            -73.9538181,
            40.7870864
          ],
          [
            -73.9541536,
            40.7872279
          ],
          [
            -73.9557237,
            40.7878894
          ],
          [
            -73.9604089,
            40.7815447
          ],
          [
            -73.9539823,
            40.7788333
          ],
          [
            -73.9493302,
            40.7851967
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
```

I am getting the above data from an API and I have POJOs to save all the other data. I am however failing to create a polygon from the coordinates in order to save it in MySQL and retrieve later.

```
    @JsonProperty("coordinates")
    private Polygon geomertry;
```

The above won't work. I am fairly new to this so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use arrays or `List`.

```
@JsonProperty("coordinates")
private double[][][] geomertry;
```